# How to get required text from a string using python?

Tags: python, string

I have a multiline string from which I need to split and get only required texts. I should not count the index manually because the length might change every time.

My Python code

```py
test= "all:qwe:ew1:aq-nps-3:977232323342:isc/isc-04987s4c12399a1sa"
a= test.split()
print(a)

Now I am stuck here on how to proceed further.
```

I want to get "aq-nps-3" and "isc-04987s4c12399a1sa" values alone from a string and store it in different variable. Can anyone guide me on further steps? Is it a good way to count index manually or how I can get these required values alone.

Expected results:

```
a= aq-nps-3
b= isc-04987s4c12399a1sa
```

Comment: You need to define a rules of what makes your "required texts" as **required**

Comment: sorry I did not get you

Comment: I agree with @RomanPerekhrest,   Why you need that thing only, Are there any patters for it or identity to extract the text?

Comment: yes I need that particular texts only for my future validation purpose

Comment: what if the statement changes to something else? I suggest to make a generic patter instead of just extracting from the string.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should be splitting by the `:` character:

```
 bits = test.split(':')
 a = bits[3]
 b = bits[5]
 print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to crack with below code,

```
test= "all:qwe:ew1:aq-nps-3:977232323342:isc/isc-04987s4c12399a1sa"
a= (test.split(':')[-1]).split('/')[-1]
print(a)
```